# Memory upgrade compatibility issue

Tags: memory, motherboard, ddr3

I have an ASUSTek P8P67-M (LGA1155) motherboard on my desktop / home computer, which actually has only 8GB RAM, based on two DDR3 1333MHz (PC3-10700H) Corsair 4GB Modules (Part Number CMV4GX3M1A1333C9).

The closest module I've found to add for a total 16GB (two empty slots) are Kingston ones ([Datasheet](http://www.kingston.com/dataSheets/KVR13N9S8_4.pdf)), but I'm only troubled about a spec that I don't know what it means. The Corsair ones are 10700, but the Kingston are 10600. What's that? Would they work together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as memory modules have the same number of pins, they are theoretically compatible. Memory modules are smart: they have controller chips that the memory controller on the motherboard communicates with to determine the speed, latency, and other settings. The speed is really the maximum speed: if you mix speeds, the motherboard will use the slowest speed to avoid harming chips that cannot go faster.

However, in your specific scenario, the two speeds (10600 and 10700) are equivalent. The number comes from the peak transfer rate of 10,666.67 MB/sec. The standard rating is 10600, or 10666.67 rounded *down* to the nearest 100. However, some manufacturers round *up* to 10700 to make it sound faster.

Your memory modules are rated at the same speed: even if they were not, they should still work regardless because the motherboard will use the slowest speed of all modules.

**However** not all modules work together on all motherboards. Some modules and some motherboards are sensitive to minor differences between memory modules, and there is no guarantee that they will work together correctly. Most people will recommend using a matched set of modules that are listed by the motherboard manufacturer as being compatible. Given the insane speeds of modern RAM, it can be very fickle at times.

Comment: awesome answer, great insight!