# New memory not working

Tags: memory

Following with "[Memory upgrade compatibility issue](https://superuser.com/questions/1141549/memory-upgrade-compatibility-issue)", I finally bought 2 Kingston KVR13N9S8/4 modules, added them to the existing 2 CMV4GX3M1A1333C9 Corsair modules on my ASUSTek P8P67-M (LGA1155) motherboard and the result is that it won't boot at all. No screen output, error messages, not beeps, nothing.

Tried replacing the Corsair modules with the Kingston only and, same effect. After reverting to the original configuration of only the Corsair modules BIOS told me "overclocking failed". What could be wrong?

Comment: Have you checked that the new RAM modules are supported by the motherboard in your motherboard manual? Is the configuration supported? Is there a recommended voltage and frequency?

Comment: @EricF I  haven't checked any of the above :( What "configuration" should be supported? The 4x4GB?

Comment: Read in your motherboard manual. It will state what can be in each memory slot in conjunction with the other slots. This will be listed as maximum memory per module, frequency, and memory manufacturer even. Make sure not to assume all ram will work on all motherboards

Comment: Reset all memory timing and voltages to their defaults.

Comment: both sets of chips match in frequency, size and voltage, and that motherboard doesn't need to overclock to reach 1333MHz, so somthing is off. I'd look up how to clear the CMOS for your board, and reset it. that should clear any existing overclock configuration (but as I said, there shouldn't be one; you shouldn't overclock that RAM beyond its native 1333). If you are really getting no beeps, then try reseating everything. do the fans come on?

Comment: mmmm....just realized that the Corsairs are non-ECC (so is the motherboard) and Kingstons do support ECC, would that be a problem?

Comment: @GonzaloVasquez, where did you see the Kingston KVR13N9S8/4 having ECC? http://www.kingston.com/dataSheets/KVR13N9S8_4.pdf

Comment: @AliChen not sure where, but definetely not in the datasheet 

Comment: I just have upgraded an old DELL D820 laptop to 4GB (2x2) SODIMMs. At first, when I put both new SODIMMs, the laptop went dead, a pair of LED was only blinking. Tried twice, same effect. Then I removed the secondary (user accessible) SODIMM, leaving only the main one (under keyboard), and whoa, I got a BIOS warning - "memory size was changed". Then it was about a minute timeout, before an option to enter BIOS setup appeared. After exiting BIOS, Win booted fine. Then I repeated the process with the second SODIMM, and eventually everything ended fine. Lesson: BIOSes do have "security".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid you might be out of luck. The DRAM timing is really tight these days, setup and hold times on memory interfaces are very dependent on quality of particular board layout, and different DIMMs provide different loads to the bus, so results may vary. Although this particular board is made in 2012 when DDR3 has matured, still there could be quirks in DDR controller tune-ups. Also, modern BIOS/UEFI have some intelligent algorithms to tune memeory channel settings, and the message "overclocking failed" is a likely an indication that the tune-up has failed.

I would try:

1. Totally reset BIOS to factory default. Sometimes a simple jumper-based reset does not fully work, and you need to remove CMOS battery, and short the CMOS rails for a second.
2. Try first a pair of KINFGSTON DIMMs, to see if the BIOS can accommodate one load of this memory;
3. Use fail-safe defaults in the BIOS, and definitely disable any "overclocking" option. ASUS has a lot of crazy tune-ups to appeal to gamer's community.
4. Try to start the system several times, with full power off (including disconneting it from AC. The BIOS might have an iterative fail-safe algorithm, which "remembers" previous state of failures, and iteratively scales the memory setting back.
5. Be patient, BIOS can use some test runs to check memory stability, and big memories takes this longer.
6. Use the latest BIOS, always.

However, it is important to note that QVL ([Qualified Vendor List](http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/LGA1155/P8P67_LX/Intel-P67-4DIMM-Module-QVL.pdf?_ga=1.116563648.733199826.1478280956)) for this board does not list a single case of successful 4x4GB configuration (although my interpretation of the document might be incorrect). And the Kingston KVR13N9S8/4 is not in that list. So your chances are low.

Good luck.

Comment: Actually last night I went through al the above steps and it worked, including the ones discussed in the comments section of the question itself. But I guess it all boiled down to "layer 8" issue, as it seems I hadn't properly inserted the modules into the slots: only one side had the "click" / clip thingy, and the other end just had to rely on applying enough pressure to insert it fully :P

Comment: I am glad you succeeded, and that my worries were unfounded. Yes, the lack of "click on both ends" is detrimental.

Comment: Ali, that certainly is a hardware design failure from my point of view

Comment: Actually, the DIMM sockets were always that way, as long as I remember. Having done the memory shuffling maybe several hundred times myself, I still had few hiccups of this sort. You are not alone...